# Angular 2 Observable.retryWhen doesn't include status in error

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to get my code updated so that I am able to use refresh tokens to keep a user logged in. I intend to do this using the `Observable.retryWhen` method. However I am running into an issue where the error being passed to my retry method has a type of `Subject` instead of `Response` like I expected and have gotten in the past. This is an issue because I need to check if the status is a 401 and `Subject` doesn't include the status of the response. Also the catch works as expected passing a `Response` object to the `handleError` method.

**http.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ) { }

  public get(url: string, headers?: Headers): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url, this.getHeaders(headers))
      .map(this.extractData)
      .retryWhen(this.handleRetry)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleRetry(error: Response): Observable<any> {
    if (error.status === 401) { // I can't get past here because error doesn't include status and is the wrong type.
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Error equals

```
Subject {
  closed: false
  hasError: false
  isStopped: false
  observers: Array(0)
  thrownError: null
  _isScalar: false
}
```

While I expect error to equal something similar to:

```
Response {
  headers: Headers
  ok: false
  status: 401
  statusText: "OK"
  type: 2
  url: "..."
  _body: ""
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function passed to [`retryWhen`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retryWhen) does not receive an `Error`; it receives an `Observable<Error>` argument. That is why you are seeing a `Subject`.

The logic in your `handleRetry` function needs to be composed into an observable, from within which any effected errors can be inspected. `mergeMap` could be used to retry some errors and fail others. For example:

```ts
private handleRetry(errors: Observable<Response>): Observable<any> {

  return errors.mergeMap(error => {

    if (error.status === 401) {

      // Add an authorization header, perhaps.
      // ...
      // Emit anything (the error instance, for example) to retry:
      return Observable.of(error);

    } else {

      // Throw the error to give up retrying:
      return Observable.throw(error);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey I think your response focuses more on what to do once I determine error.status === 401. I intentionally left that out because I know exactly what to do once the error has a status. My question is why doesn't my error have a status. Until I can check the status the behavior of the retry handler doesn't matter since it's behavior depends on that status.

Please focus your answer on the question at hand, why does error not have status and please don't worry about what the retry handler returns or what it's behavior is aside from it should have access to the status of the response.

Comment: The key point in the answer is the *first* sentence. Your `handleRetry` function does *not* receive an `Error` argument. The rest is context.

Comment: It looks like the relevant bit of your answer is using mergeMap. I'll mark this as correct if you can make the answer more concise around that. As is I feel you focused on how to use retryWhen and it's difficult to find the one relevant line of code necessary to get the error status. Things like binding `this` and returning observables are totally outside the scope of the question and just confuse the answer.

Comment: Edited for conciseness.