# How to handle error when implementing Exponential backoff function?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-http

I use the concept of the **[backoff](https://angular.io/guide/practical-observable-usage)** method to retry the request if internal Server Error occurs. I mean not **`401`**, **`403`** or similar. My target is to retry the request if the server doesn't respond and/or it takes too long to send a response, for instance in case of **`pending`** status. And I do have defined timeout limit for that (in the service).

My Issue is that the **`retryWhen`** function is being invoked in all the cases/errors including **`401`**.

I believe that I might have to restructure my function/code to make it work. I'm struggling with that, but just can't make it working as it expected.

The **`retryWhen`** function returns an observable stream that indicates when to retry and therefore it can't work in my code as it should be.

```
public userLogin(userName, userPass: string) {
    this.theService.login(userName, userPass)
        .retryWhen(attempts => Observable.range(1, 3)
            .zip(attempts, i => i)
            .mergeMap(i => {
                console.log("delay retry by " + i + " second(s)");
                // Show a message to user to wait
                if ( i === 3 ) {
                    // Show Server doesn't respond... try later
                }
                return Observable.timer(i * 3000);
            })
        ).subscribe(
        res => {
            // handle and show response result
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
            if ( err === 401 ) {
                // handle 401 error
            } else {
                // handle other error
            }
        }
    );
}
```

The following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377619/angular-2-observable-retrywhen-doesnt-include-status-in-error?rq=1) is also a kind of handling the same issue and I tried to use the hint regarding `mergeMap(error => {...})`, but it didn't work for me.

Any idea please how I should restructure my code to retry the request just in case of internal server error or a kind of? as I mentioned no **`401`**, **`403`** or similar.

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cwnknr

Comment: Anyway, as I see it you have to throw an error in your service when your special case happens. I think you are missing that part.

Comment: What do you want to the stream if it is a 401, 403, ...? Do you want it to error, complete, ignore?

Comment: @bygrace: good question! in this case of `401` I would throw an error message regarding credentials etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-throw the blacklisted errors in the `retryWhen` operator as follows:

```js
/**
 * Performs a retry on an exponential backoff with an upper bounds.
 * Will rethrow the error if it is in the blacklist or the retry
 * attempts have exceeded the maximum.
 * @param {number} initialDelay
 * @param {number} maxRetry - maximum number of times to retry
 * @param {number[]} errorWhiteList - whitelist of errors to retry on (non-transient)
 */
function expontentialRetry(
  initialDelay,
  maxRetry,
  errorWhiteList
) {
  return (errors) => errors.scan((retryAttempts, error) => {
      if(!errorWhiteList.includes(error.status) || retryAttempts > maxRetry) {
        throw error;
      }
      return retryAttempts + 1;
    }, 0).switchMap((retryAttempts) => {
        // calculate exponential backoff
        let delay = Math.pow(2, retryAttempts - 1) * initialDelay;
        console.log(`Retry attempt #${retryAttempts} in ${delay}ms`);
        return Rx.Observable.timer(delay);
    });
}

let count = 0;
const fakeApiCall = Rx.Observable.create((o) => {
  if (count < 5) {
    o.error({ status: 504 });
  } else {
    o.error({ status: 500 });
  }
  count++;
});

fakeApiCall.retryWhen(expontentialRetry(100, 10, [504]))
.subscribe(
  (x) => { console.log('next', x); },
  (error) => { console.log('error', error); },
  () => { console.log('complete'); }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.10/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok, I did implement it... but it always throws me `401` even in case if I use correct credentials but the I reduce the connection in order to check `timeout` issue, I mean `504` error which is actually a timeout error. I did use `504` instead of `500` in order to catch `timeout` case.

Comment: @k.vincent sorry I'm not clear on what you are saying. Is there some case that you wan't handled that isn't?

Comment: Tanks first - I did implement it but it seems that it doesn't work foe me. I might did understand something wrong. My main Target is to retry and throw specific error just in case of `timeout`. in other words if the server isn't responding. i think this would be `504`. In all the other cases/errors it should not `retry` and should go to the next step which is `res => {....}, err => {...}`

Comment: @k.vincent It sounds like you want a whitelist instead of a blacklist. That is to say that you want to define the errors to retry on rather than those to not retry on. I updated the answer accordingly. Let me know if that is what you are intending.

Comment: I first face an issue even if I enter the correct `credentials`.  it retry 5 times and throws immediately error. This should not be the case.
Am I doing something wrong when implenmting it in my code: `this.theService.login(userName, userPass)Observable.create((o) => {if (count < 5) { o.error({ code: 504 }); } else { o.error({ code: 500 }); } count++; }).retryWhen(this.expontentialRetry(100, 10, [504])).subscribe(  (res) => {..}, (error) => {....}`?

Comment: Could we please continue on chat, If you don't mind? My self can't create a chat cause I do not enough reputation ;-(

Comment: @k.vincent The `Rx.Observable.create(...)` is just for the example to mimic an api call. In reality you should be doing `this.theService.login(userName, userPass).retryWhen(this.expontentialRetry(100, 10, [504]))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169859/discussion-between-k-vincent-and-bygrace).

Comment: would `timeoutWith(4000, Observable.throw({ status: 504 }))` this catch - let's say - the real `HTTP 504`?

Comment: @k.vincent that code just throws an error that looks like part of a 504 error. The real one will be thrown by the http client. The retry should see both.